# React Native <TochableOpacity> is dimming companion component

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning React Native while trying to build a simple Android app. 
I have two components (TextInput and Button)  aligned side by side. The TextInput component is wrapped in   and the Button component is wrapped in a regular  outside of . Yet somehow whenever I click on TextInput, both the Button and the TextInput get dimmed.

How can I make it work so that only TextInput Component gets dimmed but not the button?

Thank you

```js
export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;
    return [
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.todoItem}
        onPress={() => this.props.toggleDone()} 
      >
        <Text
          style={(todoItem.done) ? { color: '#AAAAAA' } : { color: '#313131' }}>
          {todoItem.title}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>,

      <View style={styles.emailButton}> 
        <Button
          style={styles.removeButton}
          title="Remove"
          color={(todoItem.done) ? 'rgba(200,0,0,0.5)' : 'rgba(255,0,0,1)'}
          onPress={() => this.props.removeTodo()}
        />
      </View>,
    ];
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  todoItem: {
    width: '70%',
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingLeft: 15
  },
  removeButton: {
    width: '30%',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  }
});
```

Comment: you can use the `activeOpacity` prop of `TouchableOpacity` and in the range of 0 to 1.

Comment: What are the styles of "emailButton"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below example and let me know if it was helpful

```
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      todoItem:false
    }
  }

  toggleDone = () => {
    this.setState({
      todoItem:true
    })
  }
  removeTodo = () => {
    this.setState({
      todoItem:true
    })
  }

  render() {
   // const todoItem = this.props.todoItem; 

    return [
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.todoItem}
        onPress={this.toggleDone}>
        <Text
          style={this.state.todoItem ? { color: '#AAAAAA' } : { color: '#313131' }}> 
          {`text...........`} 
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>,

      <View style={styles.emailButton}>
        <Button
          style={styles.removeButton}
          title="Remove"
          color={'rgba(255,0,0,1)'}
          onPress={this.removeTodo} 
        />
      </View>,
    ];
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  todoItem: {
    width: '70%',
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start', 

    paddingLeft: 15,
  },

  removeButton: {
    width: '30%',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @SRanuluge. That worked. But I am still struggling on how to integrate the code with what I have. I think need to open a new thread with the issue I am having.